# listing couples from base in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create a predicate able to list every possible couple from a set of man and woman. But my trials return me true even if the man or woman does not belong to my knowledge base.

```
man(al).
man(john).

woman(elsa).
woman(julia).

couple(man(_),woman(_)).
```

Query:

```
?- couple(X,Y).
```

Answer:

```
X: al
Y: elsa

X: al
Y: julia

X: john
Y: elsa
...
```

NOTE: I'm using SWI-Prolog.

Comment: please edit your question with an example query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert but this definition seems to do the job:

```
couple(M, W) :- man(M), woman(W).
couple(W, M) :- man(M), woman(W).
```

If you are only interested in *unique* couples, then you can discard either one of the lines.